# What are the redexes in this Haskell expression?

Tags: haskell, lambda, expression, monads, redex

I am learning Haskell for a university course and i have a question about reducible expressions (redexes). I understand the concept yet I still have some questions that I can't seem to figure out on my own.

Lets say you would want to find all the reducible expressions in an expression, like this:

```
head (map (+1) (3:repeat 3))
```

In this expression an obvious redex would be `map (+1) (3:repeat 3))` because it matches to the definition of `map`, so Haskell would "reduce" the expression and `map` would increment the `3` and `4:map (+1) (repeat 3)`. would be reduced next.

The question I have is:

Is `head (map (+1) (3:repeat 3))` already a redex, before `map` is evaluated?

Because the "input" of `head` does not match the constructor of a list (which is what `head` is looking for), I am confused about whether it still is a redex because logically it can't  get reduced yet, but the definitions online seem to be saying that it would be.

Comment: Can you link to the definitions  online that you mention?

Answer (score 3):

Haskell's evaluation is lazy: it proceeds by *topmost leftmost* redex strategy (at least conceptually): it reduces the leftmost among the topmost redexes.

Presumably `head` is defined as

```
head xs = case xs of (x:_) -> x
```

so then its application to whatever expression *is indeed* a redex -- an expression in need of reducing. Which proceeds according to the definition of `head`,

```
head (map (+1) (3:repeat 3))
=
case (map (+1) (3:repeat 3)) of (x:_) -> x
=
```

(or we could say that `head` itself is the topmost leftmost redex, which reduces to its definition, first; and if we'd written the above as `((\xs -> case xs of (x:_) -> x) (map (+1) (3:repeat 3)))` we'd get to the same outcome, just a bit more tediously).

A primary forcing primitive is `case`. Now *it* needs to perform the pattern match, so it must find out the value of its scrutinee expression (only to the extent that the pattern match becomes possible). To do that it must now work according to the definition of `map` which is presumably

```
map f xs = case xs of { (x:ys) -> f x : map f ys
                      ; [] -> [] }
```

so it becomes

```
case (map (+1) (3:repeat 3)) of (x:_) -> x
=
case (case (3:repeat 3) of 
         { (x:ys      ) -> (+1) x : map (+1) ys
                   ; [] -> [] } )
                             of (x:_) -> x
=
```

At this point the inner `case` expression *can* be reduced,

```
case (let { x=3 ; ys=repeat 3} in 
        (+1) x : map (+1) ys )
  of (x        : _                  ) -> x
=
```

and now the *outer* `case`'s pattern matching becomes possible,

```
case (let { x=3 } in 
        (+1) x               )
  of (x                             ) -> x
=
      let { x=3 } in 
        (+1) x 
=
        (+1) 3 
=
        4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense.